# Mass User Locking/Unlocking

Tags: sap-basis

Hey guys I was just wondering how you go about doing mass user locking/unlocking. More specifically what are the best ways to do so? Any insights would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is hardly a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to upload the list of users to be locked in SU10 and lock them. The other way which I know is to create a custom program using BAPI_USER_LOCK & BAPI_USER_UNLOCK.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SU10`, Luke!

[image]

This transaction allows many other mass operations besides (un)locking.

Comment: @szako, exactly :) just faulty keyboard